# Primefaces tooltip displaying bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

primefaces tooltip displaying bottom of the page.. when i mouse ohover on tooltip message displaying bottom of the page.
primefaces tooltip displaying bottom of the page.. when i mouse ohover on tooltip message displaying bottom of the page.
here is my code and image link..
http://postimg.org/image/k9maot5gl/

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
            <h:head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">       </meta>
            <title>about</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap -->

            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            <link href="css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            <link href="fonts/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
          </h:head>         <h:body styleclass="bgcolor">
         <header>
            <div class="subheader">
                <div class="container subblckbg ">
                    <div class="logo maplogo homelogo">
                        <h:outputLink value="home.xhtml">
                            <p:graphicImage value="images/logo.png" alt="" width="278"></p:graphicImage>
                        </h:outputLink>
                    </div>
                    <div class="userloginbtn">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <p:graphicImage value="images/user_icon.png" alt="" title="" width="24"></p:graphicImage>
                        </a>

                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty sessionBean.personDto}">
                                <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu"
                                    class="dropdown-menu dpmenu logindpm">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="ldropmenu">
                                            <h3>Login</h3>
                                            <form class="lpopup" id="loginForm" name="loginForm"
                                                ........


                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty sessionBean.personDto}">
                                <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu"
                                    class="dpmenu logindpm dropdown-menu"
                                    style="padding: 0 !important;">
                                    <li>
                                        <form style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom:0px; margin-right: 0px;"
                                            id="logoutForm" name="loginForm"
                                            action="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/logout/process"
                                            method="post">
                                            ...........
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </div>
                    <div class="headsocial hmsclimg">
                             <ul>
                             <li class="callusbox">
                                <a href="callto:+91-XXXXXXXXXX">
                                <p:graphicImage styleClass="socialcall" id="contactphonenu" alt=""/>
                                <p:tooltip  for="contactphonenu" value="callto:+91-XXXXXXXXXX" style="background-color:#fff;  z-index: 100000000 !important;"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                             </ul>
                     </div>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top mapnav">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="navbar">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse mapheader">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li ><a href="./home.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="./about.xhtml">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="./contact.xhtml">Contact</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse --> </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
                  <div class="mytabbox maptabbox">
                            <div class="container subblckbg">   
                                <div class="tab-content clearfix mapsubhed">
                                  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Pathology">
                                    <div class="applist">
                                        <h2>About</h2>
                                      </div>                              
                                  </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
              </header> 
                 <section>
                        <div class="about_bg">
                        <img title="" alt="" src="images/about_bg.jpg"></img>
                        </div>
                 </section>
              <div class="container app_page brdtop aboutpagelas">
                  <div class="confmapp ">
                                <div class="app_ldesc conf_about">
                                  <h2> About Us</h2>
                                </div>
                     </div>  
                    <div class="row confmappmid">
                        <div class="col-md-12 about_info">
                            <div class="abouttitle">
                                <p>......</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

              <footer class="static">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="hfooter hlfooter">
                                <ul>
                                 <li> <a href="./home.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="./about.xhtml"  class="fnavactive">About</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="./contact.xhtml">Contact</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="./terms.xhtml">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="./privacypolicy.xhtml">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="./faq.xhtml">Faq</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="hfooter">
                                <p>footer ontent</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
               </footer>




            <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>


            <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#ex1").slider({});  
            $("#ex2").slider({});  
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $(".myacclink").click(function(){
                    $(".healthclinics").toggle();
                });
                $(".logindpm").click(function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });
            });
            </script>
        </body>
        </h:body>
        </h:html>
```

Comment: Might be unrelated to your actual problem, but also might be related: Including jquery manually can mess lots of things up in PrimeFaces (search stackoverflow, not PF to 'blame') Including bootstrap css can mess things up in PrimeFaces (search Stackoverflow, not PF to 'blame')

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be about `<a>` tag.

You can try using `<h:outputLink>` tag instead of `<a>` tag, like this:

```
<div class="headsocial hmsclimg">
    <ul>
        <li class="callusbox">
            <h:outputLink value="callto:+91-XXXXXXXXXX" id="contactphonenu">
                <p:graphicImage styleClass="socialcall" alt=""/>
            </h:outputLink>
            <p:tooltip  for="contactphonenu" value="callto:+91-XXXXXXXXXX" style="background-color:#fff;  z-index: 100000000 !important;"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that id field should be on `<h:outputLink>` tag, not in `<p:graphicImage>`

Yoo can see a working example here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml