# primefaces tooltip rendering at the bottom of the page when validation fails

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, tooltip

I am trying to learn JSF and I created a simple form using PrimeFaces, jQuery and plain old HTML, CSS and JS

Here is the piece of my JSF page:

```
<h:body>
    <div class="test-form">
        <div class="test-body">

            <h:form id="testForm">
                <div class="row" style="height: 10px;"></div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{testController.firstName}" required="true"
                                 placeholder="First Name" styleClass="form-control">
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:tooltip for="firstName" position="top" hideEffect="fade" showEffect="fade" >
                        <p:message for="firstName" />
                    </p:tooltip>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{testController.lastName}" required="true"
                                 placeholder="Last Name" styleClass="form-control">
                    </p:inputText>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <p:inputText type="email" id="emailAddress" value="#{testController.email}" required="true"
                                 placeholder="Email" styleClass="form-control">
                    </p:inputText>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <p:password id="password1" styleClass="form-control" value="#{testController.password}"
                                required="true" placeholder="Password" match="password2">
                    </p:password>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <p:password id="password2" styleClass="form-control"
                                value="#{testController.passwordReType}"
                                required="true" placeholder="Retype password">
                    </p:password>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <p:commandButton style="padding: 0.3em;" value="Test"
                                         class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"
                                         update="testForm"
                                         action="#{testController.test}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </h:form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="resources/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</h:body>
```

I have tried looking online " [similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976483/primefaces-tooltip-displaying-bottom-of-the-page) " and even though header might be the same of this question, answer is not useful for me.

I have attached an image of when I press "Register" button with empty first name and hover over the input field, the error tooltip is shown at the bottom of the page[image]

Comment: You should'nt import jquery, Primefaces will do it for you as long as you have a h:head. Bootstrap I'm not sure about - what happens if you remove both?

Comment: Try removing the 'has-feedback' class

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar The jQuery is for some other stuff that I am doing on the page, but I can try and manage with regular JS. Ill try removing both.

Comment: @Kukeltje Let me try that as well.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Removing those scripts did the trick. I never knew using those would cause so much trouble. Thanks a lot buddy. If you dont mind me asking, how did it occur to you that it might be the cause of the issue

Comment: That knowledge came through reading a lot of SO questions where this is stated multiple times **and** knowing PF already includes jquery (in a 1.x version and that using two different versions of a same library in a page can/will cause problems in general

Comment: @Kukeltje That makes sense.